# How to create a condition for this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

Sample Table:

```
Id |Acc_Code|Description       |Balance   | Acclevel| Acctype| Exttype|
--- -------- ----------------- |--------  |-------- | -------| -------|
1  |SA      |Sales             |   0.00   |   1     |  SA    |        |
2  |CS      |Cost of Sales     |   0.00   |   1     |  CS    |        |
3  |5000/001|Revenue           |  94.34   |   2     |  SA    |        |
4  |5000/090|Sales(Local)      |  62.83   |   2     |  SA    |        |
5  |7000/000|Manufacturing Acc |-250.80   |   2     |  CS    | MA     |
6  |7000/200|Manufacturing Acc | 178.00   |   2     |  CS    |        |
```

This is a sample data of a temporary table which would be used to be inserted into another temporary table that would calculate the data for Profit and Loss Statement (For Manufacturing related Accounts only).

In this case, the `acc_code` for Manufacturing accounts start from `7000/000` and separated/partitioned for each following `Exttype`.

Eg: We start from the exttype of `MA` and based on its `acclevel` (could be 2 or more) until the next exttype.

The idea is we get the manufacturing accounts by `SELECT` `FROM` `tmp_acc_list` `WHERE` `acc_code` `BETWEEN` `@start_acc_code` (7000/000 in this case) `AND` `@end_acc_code` (the data before the next exttype)

- I don't know what the exttype is, I'm still learning the tables.

How do we create the `@end_acc_code` part out from this sample table?

Comment: can you post more sample data up to next set of MA and show the expected result

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how the `exttype` is supposed to function, there is only one record that has an exttype `MA` in the real table, So for expected results, I would say that there would barely have any data,  maybe a couple of rows instead of the usual 20+ rows

Comment: You didn't write what should this be ordered by. Also I don't see what `acclevel` has to do with anything

Comment: Basically I want something like `WHERE` acc_code `BETWEEN` `7000/000`  `AND` `Right Before the exttype after MA`

Comment: @GrzegorzW `acclevel` is how deep the level of the account is, like COST OF SALES is 1, therefore it has no parent. If you look at other rows with `acclevel` 2, they have parents, and this could go deeper with an account having a child, etc.

Comment: so what is the input to the query ? @start_acc_code = '7000/000' ? or exttype = 'MA' ?

Comment: I want to know the @end_acc_code part which is the last acc_code which belongs to the acclevel of `MA`

Comment: yes. But what is the starting information ? 7000/000 or MA ?

Comment: starts from 7000/000

Answer (score 0):

So here is a all in one script.

I created Your table for test:

```
create table #tmp_acc_list(
    Id numeric, 
    Acc_Code nvarchar(100), 
    Acclevel numeric, 
    Acctype nvarchar(100), 
    Exttype nvarchar(100));
GO

insert into #tmp_acc_list(Id, Acc_Code, Acclevel, Acctype, Exttype)
select 1 , 'SA', 1,'SA', null union all
select 2 , 'CS', 1,'CS', null union all
select 3 , '5000/001', 2,'SA', null union all
select 4 , '5000/090', 2,'SA', null union all
select 5 , '7000/000', 2,'CS', 'MA' union all
select 6 , '7000/200', 2,'CS', null
;
```

Then comes the query:

```
with OrderedTable as -- to order the table is Id is not an order
(
    select 
    t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (
        order by id asc  --use any ordering You need here
        ) 
        as RowNum 
    from
    #tmp_acc_list as t
),
MarkedTable as -- mark with common number
(
    select 
    t.*, 
    Max(case when t.Exttype is null then null else t.RowNum end) 
       over (order by t.RowNum) as GroupRownum
    from OrderedTable as t
),
GroupedTable as -- add group Exttype
(
    select 
    t.Id, t.Acc_Code, t.Acclevel, t.Acctype, t.Exttype, 
    max(t.Exttype) over (partition by t.GroupRownum) as GroupExttype 
    from MarkedTable as t
)
select * from GroupedTable where GroupExttype = 'MA'
```

Is this what You need?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    
   (
        select  Id, Acc_Code
        from    tmp_acc_list
        where   Acc_Code    = '7000/000'
    ) s
    cross join tmp_acc_list a
    cross apply
    (
        select  top 1 x.Id, x.Acc_Code
        from    tmp_acc_list x
        where   x.Id        >= a.Id 
        and x.AccLevel  = a.AccLevel
        and x.Acctype   = a.Acctype
        and x.Exttype   = ''
        order by Id desc
    ) e
where   a.Id    between s.Id and e.Id
```